# How to change input value style with button

Tags: reactjs

I need to change input value style when clicked on the **B** button .

```
function Change() {
    const Bold = () => {
        /*    font-weight: bold ----> input value  */
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <button onClick={Bold}>B</button>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input/>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a tonne of ways but the barebones method would be to use a style object.

```
function Change() {
    const [fontWeight, setFontWeight] = React.useState('normal')

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <button onClick={() => setFontWeight('bold')}>B</button>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input style={{ fontWeight }} />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Code not tested, let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the function as follow:

```
function Change() {

const [fontWeight, setFontWeight] = useState('');


    const Bold = () => {
        setFontWeight('bold');
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <button onClick={Bold}>B</button>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input style={{ fontWeight }}/>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```